# Changing text inside button after every click

Tags: html, jquery, text, replace

```
<div class="arrows">
                    <button class="arrow" name="left" type="button" value="less"> << <p class="before"></p></button>
                    <button class="arrow" name="right" type="button" value="more"> >> <p class="after"></p></button>
                </div>
```

```
let table = 1;
let $arrowButton = $('.arrow:button');
    $arrowButton.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let $leftRight;
        //$($leftRight).text('');
        let arrowClick = $(this).attr("value"); 
        
        switch (arrowClick) {
            case 'less':
                table--;
                $leftRight = $('.before');
                break;
            case 'more':
                table++;
                $leftRight = $('.after');
                break;
        }
        let $addToArrow = $('<p>' + table + '</p>');
        $($leftRight).append($addToArrow);
        
        $arrowButton.on('mouseout', function() {
            $($leftRight).text('');
        });
    });
```

Must be a simple answer that I'm clearly missing but I'm trying to replace the text inside the arrow button every time it is clicked. The table is decremented/incremented depending on the left/right arrow clicked and then it should show that text replacing the previous text.

Comment: `$($leftRight).html($addToArrow);`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to clear the value before you append the new value.

In this case for example:

```
 $($leftRight).empty().append($addToArrow);
```

Comment: thank you! This works as I want.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mentioned, you just replace using `.html()`. However, I saw a few ways to optimize your code. Instead of using an actual input attribute `value` on a non-input, better to use `datasets`. Also, you can put the increment value in that dataset to make it easier to increment the variable `table`. Additionally, you can chain your listeners in jQuery, which makes for more consolidated, easier to read code.

[More about datasets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
let table = 1;
$('.arrow:button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  table += +$(this).data('value')
  $(this).find('div').html(`<p>${table}</p>`);
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).find('div').text('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrows">
  <button class="arrow" name="left" type="button" data-value="-1"> << <div></div></button>
  <button class="arrow" name="right" type="button" data-value="1"> >> <div></div></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Using a combo of this answer and another posted answer thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In  your question you state:

> and then it should show that text replacing the previous text.

Yet you are using "[append](https://api.jquery.com/append/)" here:

```
$($leftRight).append($addToArrow);
```

It looks like you want to use "[html](https://api.jquery.com/html/)" here instead, which will set the content of the element specified and thus overwrites (or replaces) existing content in it, like so:

```
$($leftRight).html($addToArrow);
```

Other notes:

1. If you want the table count to be displayed on the same line as "<<" or
   ">>" instead of below, you could use html spans (`<span></span>`)
   instead of paragraphs (`<p></p>`).
2. You can presumably omit the paragraph in the following line: `let $addToArrow = $('<p>' + table + '</p>');` because you are inserting it inside a paragraph (with either the class "before" or "after") already. It then becomes `let $addToArrow = $(table);` which means we might as well omit that line altogether and do the following to save a variable: `$($leftRight).html(table);`

Comment: I see what you're saying I'm repeating myself and adding another p element, thanks for the help.